# Convert C# bytes array function to vb.net

Tags: c#, vb.net, type-conversion

I am trying to convert this code

```
public static byte[] NewLine(this byte[] bytes, int feeds = 1)
    {
      return bytes.AddBytes(((IEnumerable<byte>) new byte[feeds]).Select<byte, byte>((Func<byte, byte>) (x => (byte) 10)).ToArray<byte>());
    }
```

online converters produce this

```
<System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Extension> _
    Public Function NewLine(ByVal bytes() As Byte, Optional ByVal feeds As Integer = 1) As Byte()
      Return bytes.AddBytes((DirectCast(New Byte(feeds - 1){}, IEnumerable(Of Byte))).Select(Of Byte, Byte)CType(Function(x) CByte(10), Func(Of Byte, Byte)).ToArray())
    End Function
```

which gives an error

> Overload resolution failed because no accessible 'Select' accepts this
>   number of type arguments.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Do you have an import for System.Linq?

Comment: yes, that is why it is saying `no select accepts ...`

Comment: that's a very convoluted way of adding `10` to a collection. Note that the value of `feeds` is ignored and 10 is added all the time. I don't see `CType` with this converter http://converter.telerik.com/

Comment: i got this with that converter `<System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Extension()> _
        Public Function NewLine2(ByVal bytes As Byte(), Optional ByVal feeds As Integer = 1) As Byte()
            Return bytes.AddBytes(DirectCast(New Byte(feeds - 1) {}, IEnumerable(Of Byte)).[Select](Of Byte, Byte)(DirectCast(Function(x) CByte(10), Func(Of Byte, Byte))).ToArray(Of Byte)())
        End Function` it still has `DirectCast` instead, which still gives the error above

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not clear to me why specifying the type arguments fails, but that isn't needed anyway - and the location of `CType` looks to be broken. If you change the `Select` call to:

```
.Select(CType(Function(x) CByte(10), Func(Of Byte, Byte)))
```

then it compiles - but you can also get rid of CType entirely:

```
.Select(Function(x) CByte(10))
```

(That simplification works in the C# code too, where this:

```
.Select<byte, byte>((Func<byte, byte>) (x => (byte) 10))
```

can be simplified to:

```
.Select(x => (byte) 10)
```